# get tag attributes from specific parents

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

There is an html-code with many similar lines. First I want to get all IDs from the li-tags. That works. Then I want to get the IDs only from the div-tags with the class-content "grouped-listing" (last lines). This don't works.

HTML:

```
<ul id="resultListItems">
    <li data-id="102292896">
        <div>
            <article data-item="result" id="result-102292896" data-obid="102292896">
                <div class="result-list-entry__grouped-listings">
                    <a href="/expose/102292896" id="result-102292896" data-go-to-expose-id="102292896" data-go-to-expose-referrer="RESULT_LIST_GROUPED">...</a>
                    <div class="slick-initialized slick-slider">
                        <div class="slick-list draggable">
                            <a href="/expose/102292896" id="result-102292896" data-go-to-expose-id="102292896" data-go-to-expose-referrer="RESULT_LIST_GROUPED">...</a>
                            <div class="slick-track" style="opacity: 1; width: 712px; transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);">
                               <div class="grouped-listing slick-slide slick-current slick-active grouped-listing--active" style="width: 162px;" data-slick-index="0" aria-hidden="false">
                                  <a href="/expose/104436157" id="result-104436157" data-go-to-expose-id="104436157" data-go-to-expose-referrer="RESULT_LIST_GROUPED">
                                  </a>
                                  <div>
                                  </div>
                               </div>
                               <div class="grouped-listing slick-slide slick-active" style="width: 162px;" data-slick-index="1" aria-hidden="false">
                                  <a href="/expose/104435708" id="result-104435708" data-go-to-expose-id="104435708" data-go-to-expose-referrer="RESULT_LIST_GROUPED">
                                  </a>
                                  <div>
                                  </div>
                               </div>
                               <div class="grouped-listing slick-slide slick-active" style="width: 162px;" data-slick-index="2" aria-hidden="false">
                                  <a href="/Suche/controller/exposeNavigation/goToExpose.go?exposeId=104434267&amp;searchUrl=%2FSuche%2FS-T%2FHaus-Kauf%2FBrandenburg%2FPotsdam&amp;referrer=RESULT_LIST_GROUPED" id="result-104434267" data-go-to-expose-id="104434267" data-go-to-expose-referrer="RESULT_LIST_GROUPED">
                                  </a>
                                  <div>
                                  </div>
                               </div>
                               <div class="grouped-listing slick-slide slick-active" style="width: 162px;" data-slick-index="3" aria-hidden="false">
                                  <a href="/expose/104418108" id="result-104418108" data-go-to-expose-id="104418108" data-go-to-expose-referrer="RESULT_LIST_GROUPED">
                                  </a>
                                  <div>
                                  </div>
                               </div>
                            </div>
```

Script that works fine:

```
try:
    get_id = soup(url, "html.parser")
    for biglist in get_id.find_all("li", {"data-id": True}):
        if (biglist.parent.get("id") == "resultListItems"):
            my_url = "https://www.abc.de/"+biglist.get("data-id")+"#/"
            print(my_url)
```

That don't works:

```
try:
    get_id = soup(url, "html.parser")
    for biglist in get_id.find_all("a", {"data-go-to-expose-id": True}):
        if (biglist.parent.get("class") == "grouped-listing"):
            my_url = "https://www.abc.de/"+biglist.get("data-id")+"#/"
            print(my_url)
```

Any idea?

EDIT: My result is displayed here: [image]
The Webpage contains more results: https://www.immobilienscout24.de/Suche/S-T/Haus-Kauf/Brandenburg/Potsdam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To search for all `<a>` tags with attribute `"data-go-to-expose-id"`, whose parent is `<div>` with class `"grouped-listing"`, you can use CSS selector

```
'div.grouped-listing a[data-go-to-expose-id]'
```

, like this:

```
data = """
<ul id="resultListItems">
    <li data-id="102292896">
        <div>
            <article data-item="result" id="result-102292896" data-obid="102292896">
                <div class="result-list-entry__grouped-listings">
                    <a href="/expose/102292896" id="result-102292896" data-go-to-expose-id="102292896" data-go-to-expose-referrer="RESULT_LIST_GROUPED">...</a>
                    <div class="slick-initialized slick-slider">
                        <div class="slick-list draggable">
                            <a href="/expose/102292896" id="result-102292896" data-go-to-expose-id="102292896" data-go-to-expose-referrer="RESULT_LIST_GROUPED">...</a>
                            <div class="slick-track" style="opacity: 1; width: 712px; transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);">
                               <div class="grouped-listing slick-slide slick-current slick-active grouped-listing--active" style="width: 162px;" data-slick-index="0" aria-hidden="false">
                                  <a href="/expose/104436157" id="result-104436157" data-go-to-expose-id="104436157" data-go-to-expose-referrer="RESULT_LIST_GROUPED">
                                  </a>
                                  <div>
                                  </div>
                               </div>
                               <div class="grouped-listing slick-slide slick-active" style="width: 162px;" data-slick-index="1" aria-hidden="false">
                                  <a href="/expose/104435708" id="result-104435708" data-go-to-expose-id="104435708" data-go-to-expose-referrer="RESULT_LIST_GROUPED">
                                  </a>
                                  <div>
                                  </div>
                               </div>
                               <div class="grouped-listing slick-slide slick-active" style="width: 162px;" data-slick-index="2" aria-hidden="false">
                                  <a href="/Suche/controller/exposeNavigation/goToExpose.go?exposeId=104434267&amp;searchUrl=%2FSuche%2FS-T%2FHaus-Kauf%2FBrandenburg%2FPotsdam&amp;referrer=RESULT_LIST_GROUPED" id="result-104434267" data-go-to-expose-id="104434267" data-go-to-expose-referrer="RESULT_LIST_GROUPED">
                                  </a>
                                  <div>
                                  </div>
                               </div>
                               <div class="grouped-listing slick-slide slick-active" style="width: 162px;" data-slick-index="3" aria-hidden="false">
                                  <a href="/expose/104418108" id="result-104418108" data-go-to-expose-id="104418108" data-go-to-expose-referrer="RESULT_LIST_GROUPED">
                                  </a>
                                  <div>
                                  </div>
                               </div>
                            </div>
"""


from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')

for a in soup.select('div.grouped-listing a[data-go-to-expose-id]'):
    my_url2 = "https://www.abc.de/"+a['data-go-to-expose-id']+"#/"
    print(my_url2)
```

This will print:

```
https://www.abc.de/104436157#/
https://www.abc.de/104435708#/
https://www.abc.de/104434267#/
https://www.abc.de/104418108#/
```

Comment: really strange. You're right, if I run only this, it's correct, but if I open the real website it detects only the first and second result.

Comment: Maybe you ca take a look at the EDIT?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this?

```
get_id = BeautifulSoup(url, "html.parser")
for biglist in get_id.find_all("a", {"data-go-to-expose-id": True}):
    x = len(biglist.parent.get("class"))
    y = biglist.parent.get("class")
    for i in range(x):
        if (y[i] == "grouped-listing"):
            my_url = "https://www.abc.de/"+biglist.get("data-go-to-expose-id")+"#/"
            print(my_url)
```

Output:

```
https://www.abc.de/102292896#/
https://www.abc.de/102292896#/
```

Comment: Thanks. Works better. I get more results, but unfortunately not all.

Comment: I see only 102292896 in your code snippet, may be you need to add a proper example to help us comprehend better.

Comment: I've entered (edited) real code. Now there are different IDs and I'll get only the IDs from the first a-tag

Comment: Please post your sample output as well.

Comment: onlye the first and second: abc.de/104436157#/
abc.de/104435708#/